# Can I have a temporary/alternative neo4j graph for testing?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm using Py2neo in a project. Most of the time the neo4j server runs on localhost so in order to connect to the graph I just do:

```
g = Graph()
```

But when I run tests I'd like connect to a different graph, preferably one I can trash without any consequencews.

I'd like to have a "production" graph, possibly set up in such a way that even though it also runs on localhost, the tests won't have access to it.

Can this be done?

**UPDATE 0** - A better way to put this question might have been how can I get my locahost Neo4J to serve up 2 databases on two different ports? Once I've got that working it's trivial ot use the REST client to connect to one or the other. I'm running the latest .deb version of Neo4J on an Ubuntu workstation (if that matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run neo4j server on a different machine and access it through REST service.

Inside the neo4j-server.properties, you can uncomment the line where it says IP address of 0.0.0.0
This would allow that server to be accessed from any place. Now I dont what with Python, but with Java I am using Java Rest library to access that server using the Java Rest Library for Neo4j. Take a look here

> https://github.com/rash805115/bookeeping/blob/master/src/main/java/database/service/impl/Neo4JRestServiceImpl.java

**Update 0:** There are three ways to complete your wish.

**Method 1:** Start neo4j instance on a separate machine. Then access that instance using some REST API. The way to do that would be to go in conf/neo4j-server.properties and then to find this line and uncomment it.

```
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

**Method 2:** Start two neo4j instances on the same machine but different port and use the REST service to access those. To do this copy the neo4j distribution into two separate folders. Then change this line in conf/neo4j-server.properties and change the port in atleast one if them.

```
First Instance - org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474
                 org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7473
Second Instance - org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=8484
                  org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=8483
```

**Method 3:** From your comments it appears you want to do this and indeed this is the easiest method. Have two separate databases on the same Neo4J Instance. **For you to do this you dont have to change any configuration files, just a line in your code.** I have not done this in python exactly, but I have done the same in Java. Let me give you the Java code and you can see how easy it is.

Production Code:

```
package rash.experiments.neo4j;

import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class Neo4JEmbedded
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("db/productiondata/");
        ExecutionEngine executionEngine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDatabaseService);

        try(Transaction transaction = graphDatabaseService.beginTx())
        {
            executionEngine.execute("create (node:Person {userId: 1})");
            transaction.success();
        }

        ExecutionResult executionResult = executionEngine.execute("match (node) return count(node)");
        System.out.println(executionResult.dumpToString());
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
package rash.experiments.neo4j;

import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class Neo4JEmbedded
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("db/testdata/");
        ExecutionEngine executionEngine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDatabaseService);

        try(Transaction transaction = graphDatabaseService.beginTx())
        {
            executionEngine.execute("create (node:Person {userId: 1})");
            transaction.success();
        }

        ExecutionResult executionResult = executionEngine.execute("match (node) return count(node)");
        System.out.println(executionResult.dumpToString());
    }
}
```

Note the difference in line:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("db/testdata/");
```

This creates two separate folders db/productiondata and db/testdata. Both of these folders contains separate data and your code can use either folder based on your requirement.

I am pretty sure, in your python code you have to do almost the same thing. Something like (Note that this code might not be correct):

```
g = Graph("/db/productiondata")
g = Graph("/db/testdata")
```

Comment: Here you go for python rest client library http://neo4j.com/developer/python/#_neo4jrestclient

Comment: Yeah, but how do I get a 2nd Neo4J db on one machine? Is this something I can set up from the config file?

Comment: Three options: 1. Another db on different machine (my answer) 2. Another port on same machine 3. Another db location on the same machine, same port. All of these things are configurable on neo4j-server.properties. For first option keep the neo4j distribution on separate machine. For second option keep the second neo4j distribution on separate location that first distribution and configure neo4j-server.properties to use different port. For third option, same as second, just change the database location to anything else.

Comment: For options 3 here is the line org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db

For option 2 here is the line org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474. Please note that there is a third option org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=/db/data/ which you DO NOT HAVE TO CHANGE if you dont want to change the actual URL to your database. This configuration is more like an alias to your actual database path.

Comment: Supposing I were to use Option 3 (adding an additional database location), how do I say that the neo4j needs to serve up a different location on a different port?

Comment: @SalimFadhley Please see the updated answer and let me know if it suits your need.

Answer (score 4):

You can have multiple instances of Neo4j running on the same machine by configuring them to use different ports, i.e. 7474 for development and 7473 for tests.

`Graph()` defaults to `http://localhost:7474/db/data/` but you can also pass a connection URI explicitly:

```
dev = Graph()
test = Graph("http://localhost:7473/db/data/")
prod = Graph("https://remotehost.com:6789/db/data/")
```

Comment: Let's say I want to run 2 neo4j servers on localhost - what's the configuration?

Comment: Basically (assuming Unix): Have them in different directories, make sure they run on different ports (conf/neo4j-server.properties) and start/stop them individually. In your client code, make sure you use the corresponding port on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a problem without a perfect solution right now. There are however a few options available which may suffice for what you need.

First, have a look at the py2neo build script: https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/blob/release/2.0.5/bau

This is a bash script that spawns a new database instance for each version that needs testing, starting up with an empty store beforehand and closing down afterwards. It uses the default port 7474 but it should be an easy change to tweak this automatically in the properties file. Specifically here, you'll probably want to look at the `test`, `neo4j_start` and `neo4j_stop` functions.

Additionally, py2neo provides an extension called **neobox**:
http://py2neo.org/2.0/ext/neobox.html

This is intended to be a quick and simple way to set up new database instances running on free ports and might be helpful in this case.

Note that generally speaking, clearing down the data store between tests is a bad idea as this is a slow operation and can seriously impact the running time of your test suite. For that reason, a test database that lives for all tests is a better idea although requires a little thought when writing tests so as they don't overlap.

Going forward, Neo4j will gain `DROP` functionality to help with this kind of work but it will likely be a few releases before this appears.